# Seems like SQL's WHERE clause and JOIN do not work together

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I am trying to make a basic forum, and I am having trouble printing just one row in SQL. Here is my PHP:

```
<?php
ob_start();

$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "MYPASSWORD";
$db = "MYDB";

$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db) or die("cannot connect to database.");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM forum WHERE fid = '{$fid}' JOIN user ON forum.creator=user.id;";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if ($result == true) {  
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
        print "<h1>{$title}</h1>";
    }
}
else { 
    print "failed to reach post.";
}

ob_flush();
```

?>

To help out, I believe everything works except for `$sql`. I have enabled `ini_set('display_errors',1);` but I am getting no error messages (excpet for my own that I made for the else statement).

Comment: How would I properly put WHERE and JOIN in a query?

Comment: Instead of `print "failed to reach post.";`, you might consider `print mysqli_error($conn);`—this would have told you that you have a syntax error near `JOIN user ...`, which should in turn have led you to check the MySQL manual for [`SELECT` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/select.html), which would have helped you understand that `JOIN` belongs in the `FROM` clause, *before* the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
SELECT * FROM forum JOIN user ON forum.creator=user.id WHERE fid = '{$fid}' ;
```

Comment: This answer is right as where clause comes after all of the joins.